# Looking at creating 400 GPO settings to STIG a server

Tags: group-policy

My task, as sys admin contractor for a gov project migrating to the cloud, is to STIG a Windows server 2012 image, and an SQL 2012 image. Then I can use the AMI copies. The gov nor the contracting company is going to put up the money to buy a tool which can do the STIGing.

So, I am looking at doing them manually using Group Polices, but before I do, I was wondering if anyone had any advice or shortcuts to share, which could minimize the pain? A fellow sys admin said that it took him 2 weeks to do it manually on a different project.

One thought I have, which I can't find any posting on, is if 1. Someone else already did it, 2. They exported the GPO settings, 3. They posted those exports for others to use?

Thanks in advance,
Hiker

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "to STIG a Windows Server image"? What is STIG? Well, I know that some say that he knows two facts about ducks and both of them are wrong, but in this context?

Comment: Piling on here, you need to explain what STIG means in order for us to even attempt to provide an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delays and I appreciate the quick inquiries. To quote a blogger, "Basically, STIGs are nothing more than alternate configurations that make commonly used applications more secure. All DoD IT assets must meet STIG compliance in some fashion before they are allowed to operate on DoD networks." Vulnerability scanners, such as Nessus and Retina, will find the vulnerabilities, which have to rectified through patching, registry changes, etc. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't the GPOs (or GPO settings) you require be dependent on the STIG definitions? You will probably have to build these manually specifically for any project/client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do contracted migrations for the financial industry and have performed staged GPO settings for multiple applications and deployments. GPO settings are XML based and theoretically, you could fashion custom deployments this way. However, very few have the expertise to do this in an automated fashion. Your best bet is to do what you hinted at. Stage templates in a lab AD environment, then export/backup those templates and import them in your production AD forests. [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754760.aspx) is a primer on the process. You will also want to familiarize yourself with the last item on the list: Migration Tables. These will save you loads of time. [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ashleymcglone/archive/2014/04/28/three-steps-to-migrate-group-policy-with-powershell.aspx) is another resource for automating GPO migrations.

Comment: McKenning, thanks for taking the time to type out these helpful steps, and with links. This is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers